# How can I implement RecyclerViews inside a single RecyclerView?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create a similar layout as the Google Play Store or the Netflix App where there is essentially multiple horizontal RecyclerViews inside a single RecyclerView. If this isn't the way they do it how do they accomplish that effect?

[image]

Right now I have successfully implemented a custom adapter that will do a single horizontal RecyclerView just fine. However I can't figure out how to put those single horizontal RecyclerViews into a RecyclerView to make a list of horizontal RecyclerViews. I have tried making another adapter to do the job, but I can't get it to work.

So simply my question is how can I make a layout similar to Netflix or the Google Play Store either using the RecyclerView method I described, or another method.

Edit:
One of the reasons I wanted to do RecyclerView inside a RecyclerView is that I would only have to instantiate it once. To use a RecyclerView you have to instantiate several things.

```
List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
VideoAdapter videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(videoList, this);
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.video_list);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
```

So one thing I'm trying to avoid is to have to do that 8 times for the different lists.

Comment: You may use multiple `recyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` to achieve play store-like look.

Answer (score 0):

A recycler view with view pager will do the trick. You will have to override getPageWidth the following way to show multiple pages in one view pager. Also, this lib can be useful if you do not want to do the work yourself. [lib](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5480)

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
float numberOfPages = 2; // You could display partial pages using a float value
return (1 / numberOfPages);
}
```